# Tabela exibe apenas o último valor do Laço de Repetição

Tags: javascript, angular

Fiz uma tabela que busca 100 itens de dentro da minha API, agora preciso numerar as linhas dessa tabela.
Para isso, criei uma **variável number** chamada colunas e fiz um **FOR**:

```
colunas: number;


linhasTeste(){
      for(let i = 1 ; i < 101; i++){
        this.colunas  = i;
        console.log('linhas:', this.colunas);
      }
  }
```

O resultado do meu console.log retornar um contador de 1 a 100 que era o esperado, porém na minha coluna linhas, somente o último resultado do laço aparece.

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons[0]">
    <td>
      {{colunas}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{pokemon.name}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{pokemon.url}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</tbody>
```

Como posso fazer para exibir os números em ordem crescente em minha tabela de 1 até 100? Obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não precisa disso, o **ngFor** já possui um índice para poder ser utilizado no HTML, seria apenas fazer **`ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons[0]"; let idx = index`** e utilizar `idx` no lugar de **colunas**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu dei uma olhada na documentação do Angular: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

E vi que em todo laço `ngFor` o angular fornece algumas variáveis para você, e entre elas, ele fornece a `index`, que é o que você precisa. Aí o html poderia ficar assim:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons[0]">
    <td>
      {{index + 1}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{pokemon.name}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{pokemon.url}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</tbody>
```

Ou se quiser utilizar o nome `colunas` ao invés de `index`.

```html
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons[0]; index as colunas">
    <td>
      {{colunas + 1}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{pokemon.name}}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{pokemon.url}}
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</tbody>
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:** Foi necessário colocar o `+ 1` porque o valor do `index` começa em zero, não em 1.

Comment: boa só colocaria index+1 pq começa em 0

Comment: verdade... Vou corrigir ali